# Finding difference of sets of frozensets

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

If I do:

```
set({frozenset({1,2}), frozenset({1})}) - set(frozenset({1}))
```

I would expect:

```
{frozenset({1, 2})}
```

as the result but actually I get:

```
{frozenset({1}), frozenset({1, 2})}
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you do `set(frozenset({1}))` that's actually `{1}`. If you try:

```
set({frozenset({1,2}), frozenset({1})}) - {frozenset({1})}
```

you may get the result you want.

Comment: Brilliant and (now) obvious but it was baffling me. Many thanks.